# How can i update xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

I write `console application` program
this is my `xml file`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Settings>
      <AsteriskHost type="string">172.16.18.14</AsteriskHost>

</Settings>
```

I run this code

```
   public void Set(List<AcmSettings> acmSettings)
    {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load("Settings.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> settings = xelement.Elements();
        foreach (var item in acmSettings)
        {
            settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name).SetValue("treeee");
        }
        xelement.Save("Settings.xml");
    }
```

this my test:

```
[Test]
public void SetShouldUpdateValue()
{
    var settingsManager = new SettingsManager();
    const string newIp = "165.166.167.167";
    const string elemntName = "AsteriskHost";
    var acmSetting = new List<AcmSettings> { new AcmSettings { Name = elemntName, Value = newIp } };
    settingsManager.Set(acmSetting);
    var setting = settingsManager.Get(x => x.Name == elemntName).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsTrue(setting != null);
    Assert.IsTrue(setting.Value== newIp);

}
```

I don't have any error but my new value not save in file.

How can I update `xml node` in c#

Comment: You seem to be setting the value to the same old value. What happens if you use `.SetValue("Some new value here")`?

Comment: no i write test and check it

Comment: are you sure item.Value differs from previous value?

Comment: Your code is wrong. You are nowhere using the `newIp` variable. Just to test whether the value has been updated to it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  var acmSetting = new List<AcmSettings> { new AcmSettings { Name = elemntName, Value = newIp } };
    settingsManager.Set(acmSetting);

Comment: @DarinDimitrov       public void Set(List<AcmSettings> acmSettings)
Update again

Comment: I write console application

Comment: Wild guess: the `Settings.xml` get's copied to the Debug/Release folder and is changed there and you're checking the `Settings.xml` in your solution which will still have the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your `Set` method, and it runs ok for me. I did have to tweak your current implementation by changing just one line:

```
// settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name).SetValue("treeee");
settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name).SetValue(item.Value);
```

Perhaps the problem is with your `Get` method. Here is a quick (not production quality) `Get` implementation. Using this implementation, your unit test runs successfully.

```
// note - just a string (name) passed in
public XElement Get(string name)
{
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("Settings.xml");
    IEnumerable<XElement> settings = xelement.Elements();

    return settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

The other possibility is that, as suggested in the comments above, is that you are looking at your project XML file, and not looking at the output XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 XmlDocument xmlDom = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDom.Load("YourXMLFILEPATH.xml");
 XmlNode newXMLNode = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("/Settings/AsteriskHost");
 newXMLNode.InnerText = YourValue;
 xmlDom.Save("YourXMLFILEPATH.xml");
 Console.WriteLine(xmlDom);
```

Have you tried this ?

Comment: Please dont copy.i say that I write console application

Comment: sry i wrote for asp.net, n yeah i didnt copy , i didnt read console directly jump to xmL file, So later i formatted ur post , added tag n highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your set method like this.

```
    public void Set(List<AcmSettings> acmSettings)
    {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load("Settings.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> settings = xelement.Elements();
        foreach (var item in acmSettings)
        {
            xelement.Descendants(item.Name).FirstOrDefault().Value = item.Value;
        }
        xelement.Save("Settings.xml");
    }
```